# wifi not connected with correct password 14.04 LTS on Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 130 (rev 34)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, intel-wireless

The Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 130 (rev 34) CONNECTS really good under Windows, but it DOESN'T under Ubuntu 14.04 on a Samsung NP300E5A, (same machine with 2 operating systems)

I have tried to remove the configuration from the network-manager, then I also tried to change the WPA, WPA2, WEP 128-passphrase settings and nothing.

The wifi has been working well until the last update.

When I run as sudo the lshw and lspci commands, they detect the wifi driver as iwlwifi

I run the following 2 daily updates and nothing. The wiring connection works WELL

What else I can do?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling with WiFi settings of access point more. Restrict "n" or "bg", switch off exotic and vendor-specific options, change channels or so on.